# Complexity of Block Design?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, combinatorics

What is known about the complexity of creating Block Designs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)?

I've found one paper that creates approximately solutions using Metaheuristics that claims that Block Design is NP-Hard, citing a paper from 1978. But that paper from 1978 makes no such claim or proof.

I'm particularly interested in the special case of Projective planes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Projective_planes).

Comment: Complexity given what input? Just the number of vertices? All the parameters of the design?

Comment: Given any of the above. Happy with either complexity of specific classes or more general  results. In particular, any classes that are know to be NP-hard as claimed by previous papers.

Comment: It would help if you could include a link to the paper "that creates approximately solutions using metaheuristics". Perhaps they meant to refer to a different paper? But it is hard to tell without seeing it.